# File name get different file extension when constructing from date

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I am trying to save file with text to specific location:

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Info_" + 
     System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss" + ".txt");
string Info = "";
TextFormat(ref Info);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir.ToString(),saveFileDialog.FileName), Info);
```

so right now when I am pressing the button if gives me 
filename: `Info_2013030114511.PxP` (note ".PxP" instead of ".txt"), 
but if I will change to:

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Info_" +
   System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss" + ".TXT");
```

gives me correct result: `Info_2013030114511.TXT`

I am wondering if it's a bug or am I doing something wrong...

Comment: +1: Interesting and not immediately clear behavior (nicely explained by  Justin +1). I've added info about actual issue to title - see if you are ok with edit/feel free to revert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are supplying `"yyyyMMddhmmss.txt"` to the DateTime format function.  It is interpreting the `'t'` as the a.m./p.m. specifier.  What you mean to do is:

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Info_" + 
                          System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".txt";
```